# Android studio "run" not showing up

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to run test following this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing#java

As default, there was one test file:

`MyApplication2\app\src\androidTest\java\com\example\myapplication\ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt`

In the file, I can see "run" button when I click right mouse.

[image]

However, test file I created for the uiautomater tutorial, "ChangeTextBehaviorTest.java", on the file when I click right mouse, there is no "Run" button. So I cannnot run the test ...

`MyApplication2\app\src\androidTest\java\com\example\myapplication\ChangeTextBehaviorTest.java`

[image]

How can I solve this issue? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have not imported the correct dependency for @RunWith and others as you can see it is showing in red (error). Refer the default test file for the imports and use the same imports for your file as well.

Comment: you mean "you have not imported the correct dependency for @RunWith"? I didn't notice the red and error stuff on android studio, a lot of error, better to check them one by one, thanks fuge help.

Comment: Welcome! If u find the and useful do accept it for others to know the solution as well.

Comment: Just use the same imports as that of the default file been using and it will be fixed. But it's always better to know what u code so go through the documentation as well.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the question is now answered, I saw the same issue where I could not see the "run" button next to my instrumentation tests.

FIX: Ensure you are using the 'Debug' variant as the active build variant for the module you are testing (and the 'Release' variant).

Comment: Dude, you are a lifesaver!